# ReadList can't read ".csv" data with correct line number?

Tags: data, files-and-directories, streams

- Well, the problem was solved today.

Since `"testAll.csv"` is generated by Java/Eclipse, and I noticed that the `LineSeperator` is "\r", so I just need to assign `RecordSeperator->"\r"`.

[here](https://github.com/HyperGroups/hypergroups.github.com/blob/master/test.csv) is the sample file

```
 fList1=Import["testAll.csv","Lines"];
 length1=fList1//Length
```

I get `775108` which is right.

However when I'm trying:

```
 fList2=ReadList["testAll.csv","Records"];
 length2=fList2//Length
```

I get `768065` which is the incorrect line number, and `StringSplit` couldn't keep all lines with right column number, ie `length1` is not the same as `length2`.

I also tried to partition the file into 100 files[by `Export`], and `ReadList` works correctly!

Additionally, I've changed the `.csv` file to a `.txt` file, `ReadList` works well.

---

And I found another thing is: when I export the `fList=Import["testAll.csv","Lines"];` as 'testAll_new.csv'.

Then `ReadList["testAll_new.csv","Records"];` is right...

---

I found without right options, `Import` function also has the similar problem in auto parsing the file.

[image]

Comment: You need to provide the file or an example that shows the problem or no one here can really help.

Comment: You probably need to specify the correct `RecordSeparator`-s. It might be that your file contains a couple of them.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries strange, I found `ReadList` the new `.csv` file Generated by `Import` and `Export` by `Mathematica` is OK...

Comment: Is there a typo in your new edit ("lines" instead of "Lines")?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possible cause:

```
 f = OpenWrite["test.csv"];
 WriteString[f, "1,2,3\n\n4,5,6\n"];
 Close[f];
 FilePrint["test.csv"]
```

[image]

```
 Through[{Length, MatrixForm}@Import["test.csv", "Lines"]]
 Through[{Length, MatrixForm}@ReadList["test.csv", "Record"]]
```

[image]

`Readlist` doesn't count a blank line (double line ending) as a "record" while `Import` does

You can fix this with the option `NullRecords -> True` to `ReadList`

Interestingly if you have extra returns at the end of the file `WriteString[f, "1,2,3\n\n4,5,6\n\n\n\n"]`; `Import` ignores *those*, while `ReadList[...,NullRecords->True]` picks them up.   The `"Lines"` import format does not seem to be documented by the way.

(note with the plural "Records" I get "Records is not a valid format specification" )

Comment: I found my `line seperator` is `"\r"` that's the cause...